# htaccess : Redirect root to index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like the root ( www.example.com ) to be redirected to index.html, but if the index.html does not exist to be redirected to index.php.

Also if the URL looks like ( www.example.com/anything-here ) to be redirected to the index.php.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.cgi

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    ## I would like the root ( www.example.com ) to be redirected to the index.html only if it has nothing behide it example : www.example.com/page-login.html or www.example.com/index.php

    ## I tried the code below but it is not working

    RewriteRule ^/?$ index.html [L]

    ## The code below just rewrites for example : page-login.html to the index.php ( this code works for me )

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.css|\.js|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php

</IfModule>
```

Parts on the above code works but other parts are not working.

Any help would be great.

UPDATE SOLVED

I have solved it working code below :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

The comment below put me on the right track ;-)

Thank you Michael Berkowski

Comment: The first part of that (prefer index.html over index.php) would be accomplished if you changed the order of `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php....` as far as content goes. Do you need the browser's address bar to change to reflect index.html or index.php explicitly?

Comment: Hi, No I do not need the browser's address bar to reflect the change. Also if I change the order of the DirectoryIndex the second part of the code stops working ( just goes to the index.html not index.php )